# find a file based on date mentioned in parameter

Tags: linux, shell, pattern-matching

I have a requirement to find a file based on date provided in the parameter.
For example, I have these files:

```
XYZ.ABC.M.20200615180200.batch
XYZ.ABC.M.20200616180200.batch
XYZ.ABC.M.20200617180200.batch
```

I want the file `XYZ.ABC.M.20200615180200.batch` with date `20200615` in the file name and the format of the date provided by the parameter value is 2020-06-15.
I tried

```
date -d 2020-06-15 +%Y%m%d | xargs -I{} ls  XYZ.ABC.M.{}180200.batch
```

and it is working fine, but I don't wont to hardcode the value `180200` in the command.

```
date -d 2020-06-15 +%Y%m%d | xargs -I{} ls  XYZ.ABC.M.{}*.batch
```

is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly embed the command in the string you are looking for. Just remember not to quote the asterisk. It needs to be unquoted to be used for globbing.

```
ls "XYZ.ABC.M.$(date -d 2020-06-15 +%Y%m%d)"*.batch
```

Comment: the above command is working fine but when i am running the command from datastage server: cd #INPUT_FILE_PATH# | ls XYZ.ABC.M.$(date -d 2020-06-15 +%Y%m%d)*.batch; by adding the location the command is not working as expected.

Comment: @saddy72 Do you try that with the pipe `|` character? You should not use pipe character to execute one command after another, but the semicolon `;`. Also, "not working" does not help much to understand what error you get, if any.